# Find two integers in a sorted array such that a - b = k

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an **integer k** and an **sorted array A** (can consist of both positive and negative numbers), output **2 integers from A** such that `a-b=k` in `O(n) time` and `O(1) space`

**O(n logn) Solution:**

1. Traverse the array: `O(n)`
2. For element `a[i]`, find `a[i]+k` in the array using binary search :`O(log n)`

Total Time: `O(n logn)`

**O(n) Solution:**

1. Store all elements of the array in a Hash Table: `O(n)`
2. For element a[i], check whether a[i]+k in the hash table : `O(1)`

Total Time: `O(n)`

Space: `O(n)`

But he wants an `O(n)` solution with `O(1)` extraspace. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "ve"? "nos"?

Comment: @ninjagecko This is shorthand for 'positive' (+ve) and 'negative' (-ve)

Comment: Search time or storage time? Build a binary tree with <k on one side and >k on the other. <a> must be >= <k>.  For each item on one side of the tree do a binary search on the other side. Ok, so... It's the best I got:O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to use two pointers into the array say a and b.
Originally they both point to the beginning (`a=b=0`).

If `ar[a]+k < ar[b]`, then you advance a.

If `ar[a]+k > ar[b]`, then you advance b.

If `ar[a]+k == ar[b]`, then you have found a solution.

That's `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Comment: The OP stated the equation is `a - b = k`, which in your notation, is `ar[a] - ar[b] = k`. Your solution works if you flip your indices `a` and `b` (e.g., "if `ar[b] + k < ar[a]`, then you advance `a`". Also, to keep notation consistent with the original problem, I would use `i` instead of `a` for the first index, `j` instead of `b` for the second index, and `A` instead of `ar`. Then the solution would be `a = A[i]` and `b = A[j]`, and you would return `a` and `b`.

Comment: "if ar[b] + k < ar[a], then you advance a"is WRONG. Try it and you'll see. And the way the variables are named doesn't really matter, although I agree some choices for them are better than other :)

Answer (score 8):

Make two index pointers - Left and Right, initialize both to the start of array (0). If a[Left] + k > a[Right], increment Right, else increment Left. Stop when equal

Comment: what index are you initially assigning to Left and Right?... by there names, I am assuming `0` and `N-1` resp. and if so, increment Right will make it to point to an index out of bound of array.

Comment: @Ravi Gupta I tried to give only the idea, not solution. And incrementing of both assumes that Right cannot be at the end when starting.